# Regex with JSON text

Tags: json, regex

This is my example JSON text:

```
{"sk": "<p align=\"center\">Ahoj<\/p>","en": "<p align=\"center\">Hello<\/p>"}
```

I want to get content of `sk` for example. I tried this REGEX `/"sk":"(.*)"[,}]/`, but it returns me everything after the end.

What I have a problem with is to match `" (double quotes) followed by , (comma) OR } (curly bracket)`.

**EDIT:**

I can't use JSON parser. This JSON text is saved in the MariaDB database (this MariaDB version doesn't support JSON). I can't change its version, because it is not my server. Also I have to filter the JSON results before it gets to the server. Also it is not formatted to multiple lines (only single line).

Comment: Don't use a regexp to parse JSON, use a real JSON parser.

Comment: That's not my question... What if I **can't** use JSON parser?

Comment: Nothing in your description suggests you can't, so you can, at least in the scope of this question.

Comment: If I could then I would not even try a regex.

Comment: Why can't you use a JSON parser? What language are you working in?

Comment: Please go to this link I think it will help you for your problem https://regex101.com/r/y9MHvy/1

Comment: If you try to do it with a regexp, it will almost certain fail in some cases. JSON is too complex to parse with just a regexp.

Comment: @Barmar see my edit

Comment: So, the language in question is SQL, more specifically the dialect of MariaDB at a certain version. That's relevant info and that actually explains your reluctance to use a JSON parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just forgot the whitespace. Try this

```
"sk":[ \t]*"(.*?)"[,}]
```

https://regex101.com/r/8ukKL1/3

Comment: I have formatted that JSON text just for the question, it is in a single line.

Comment: If it's in a single line you need to use a non-greedy quantifier to keep from going too far.

Comment: but keep in mind, that this regex is not always working. e.x. when you put quotes, brackets in your json value: https://regex101.com/r/8ukKL1/2

Comment: if you want to capture everything completely regex is the wrong tool.  Then you have to count open bracket, quotes, .. manually. And it quickly becomes very complicated. So this is just a solution, if you know that your json will never look like this. When not, I would advise you to use a json parser somehow.

Answer (score 2):

Since everything is on a single line, you need to use a non-greedy quantifier so it stops at the first comma or close brace, not the last one.

You also need to match whitespace after the `:`.

```
"sk":\s*"(.*?)"[,}]
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/FwOaXg/2)

Comment: Thanks, but @Sir2B was faster.